# How did I start off with 101 reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Whereas I see others with reputation points < 101?

Does everyone start off at 101?

Comment: If you have enough reputation in any StackExchange web site (e.g., StackOverflow), you'll get extra +100 points.

Comment: Jukka is exactly right: you must have linked your other SE/SO account info to this one.

Comment: Thanks :) Now how do I mark Jukka's comment as the correct answer!!

Comment: Could someone move this to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?